# Android equivalent to Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke for windows phone?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Is there a quick-and-dirty replacement for Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke that I can use for my android application? It works gorgeously for my windows phone app, but I'm using xamarin to try to duplicate my app for android, and I can't figure out a way around that line.

Here's the code where it is being used:

```
TextView txtUSN = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtUserName);
TextView txtpwd = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtPassword);
string usn = txtUSN.Text;
string pwd = txtpwd.Text;
string requestToken = "http://192.168.0.10/cschome/webdb1.aspx?cmd=login&usn=" + user + "&pwd=" + pass;
//var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestToken));
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (new Uri (requestToken));
request.BeginGetResponse (r => {
    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    string[] tempArray = response.Split('|');
                    if (tempArray[2].Substring(0, 2) == "OK") //check to make sure the login was complete
                        {
                            if (tempArray[2].Contains("1"))//If the user is level one, dol this
                            {
                                //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EntryView.xaml?token=" + tempArray[1] + "&user=" + tempArray[3] + "&email=" + tempArray[4], UriKind.Relative));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (tempArray[2].Contains("2")) //if the user is a level 2 user, do this
                                {
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //MessageBox.Show("Error: Invalid Security Token"); //if the logon was a success, but the security token lacks a level number
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        else //logon failure caviot
                        {
                            if (response.Contains("NOK usn"))
                            {
                                //MessageBox.Show("A logon error occured. Please check your username and password and try again");
                            }
                            if (response.Contains("NOK pwd"))
                            {
                                //MessageBox.Show("Password Missmatch: Please check the spelling and capitolization");
                            }
                            if (response.Contains("NOK locked"))
                            {
                                //MessageBox.Show("The user account is locked. Please contact your helpdesk");
                            }
                        }
                    }));
            }
        }, request);
    }
```

note that there is a good amount of commented code, as I am working on making android replacements, but the key piece of broken code is the deployment.current.dispatcher bit.

If there isn't a nice way to do this, can you help me to better understand how that line works, so that I can try to make a work around?

EDIT:
I posted this question to reddit, and was directed to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, which appears to be what I need, just require me to do some re-organization

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Studio 7.3

In Latest Xamarin

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  button.IsVisible = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to run a code on the UI thread, try [Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Write your code here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity needs to call it. It looks like your code is already inside one so replace:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

with:

```
this.RunOnUiThread
```

Note that you now have created a reference to the Activity from another thread so the garbage collection can be tricky. Async await might be better option but even then there are GC issues to look for. Best option would be to create an observable pattern instead of directly calling the UI thread.